# How to download created csv file using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a file in Google Apps Script as follows

```
DocsList.createFile(
   "test.csv", 
   "Row1Col1,Row1Col2 \r\n Row2Col1,RowCol2 \r\n Row3Col1,Row3Col2");
```

How to download it programmatically (via a popup Download dialog for example) ?

Answer (score 4):

Try using [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_contentservice), you can trigger a download and even set the file name via the [TextOutput.downloadAsFile method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_textoutput#downloadAsFile). You can also set the content mime type of the returned data, though only to a [predefined enum constant](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_contentservice_mimetype). See [their examples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service).

Comment: Thanks, but whenever I try the code provided in JsonP sample, i got the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ", any idea how to test it ?

Comment: I added a new thread for the issue which exists in my last comment, if you can give a hand in this issue too, it will be great ! You may find it in the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041124/jsonp-with-google-apps-script, Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

To download a file with apps script you need to either publish the app, and use the doGet() method (otherwise the "downloadFileAs" won't work)

OR...

create the file in Drive, and provide a link in a dialog ui.
here are two options for links, one requires users to be logged in the other doesn't [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281272/initiate-a-download-from-google-apps-script)

```
  var dat=getFileDataFromAnotherFunction();
  var file = DriveApp.createFile('name.csv',dat);
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DownloadDialog');
  t.url1 = getDlUrl(file);
  t.url2 = file.getDownloadUrl().replace('&gd=true','') 
  rt =  t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  uia.showModalDialog(rt,'Download the csv')
```

where "DownloadDialog.html"

is the following file (also in the script editor )

```
<div>
<a target="_blank" href="<?= url1 ?>">  l1 </a>
<br>
<hr>
<a target="_blank" href="<?= url2 ?>"> link 2 </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: `.setSandboxMode()` is not needed anymore (and I think it would even throw an error if called)

Comment: where does getDlUrl come from?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show a download dialog at client end then following code works. It is an example for CSV file.

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput("bbb,aaa,ccc").downloadAsFile("MyData.csv")
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.CSV);
```

Comment: Not working for me in Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit). I created an Apps Script  attached to a spreadsheet that contained the above within a function.  When I try to Run the function, I see "Preparing to execute" followed by "Running function ...".  No SaveAs dialog appears and no file is written.  What else is needed to make it work?